# Blogger's conditional tags into jquery code

Tags: jquery, blogger

Is it possible to add blogger's conditional tags into jquery code? For example how can I do something like this...

```
if(cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'){...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    if (typeof _WidgetManager !== "undefined") {
        var data = _WidgetManager._GetAllData();
        if (data.blog.pageType == "item") {
            alert('item');
        }
        if (data.view.isHomepage) {
            alert('homepage');
        }
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as the code is present in the Blogger theme (Theme > Edit HTML), you can use the `b:if` conditional statements directly inside the `<script>` tags. Like for example -

```
<script>
  <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
    <!-- Do Something specific to the post page-->
  </b:if>
</script>
```

**Note:** Don't add the CDATA section to the `<script>` otherwise `<b:if>` conditions will stop working inside the `<script>` tag